# Hibernate Criteria Issue 2

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

im new to Hibernate and Criteria and im getting a little trouble with the following.
Im trying to get a list of documents and the only data i have it's the client Id. Is it possible to get the data by Hibernate?

I've got the following entities

```
@Entity
public class Document implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  
   @JoinColumn(name="documentId", referencedColumnName="id")  
    private List<Gd_Client> clientList;
   (...)

@Entity
public class Gd_Client implements Serializable {

@Id
private long clientId;
@Id
private String SecId;

(...)
```

And in the DAO:

```
public List<Document> getDocumentsbyClientId(Long clientId) {

    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Document.class);

    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("clientId",clientId));

    return crit.list();

}
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Parameter #1 has not been set.
09/11/2014 11:27:44 com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
WARNING: Exception occurred during processing request: could not execute query
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Comment: try to change this line  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("clientId",clientId)); --- >  crit.add(Restrictions.eq("Id",clientId));

Answer (score 1):

The `Criteria` is created on `Document` entity and you are trying to access a property `clientId` that is not there in `Document` entity, so hibernate gives you an exception.